# Using couple of apps simultaneously - Twitter API

Tags: twitter, limit

I suggesting the following solution to twitter API limit' let me know what you thinking.
Is it possible to register let say 2 apps in different account, each apps with their own auth key and token, then when sending the requests each time switch between the apps and users tokens, by doing so the limit is upgraded twice?.

Does any own think that’s possible or there is any other limit on the ip address of the request sander?
Thanks Barak.

Answer (score 0):

After asking the same question in the twitter Dev forum I got an answer

If you're using different accounts with different apps the limit count will be only for the app and not for the computer that send the requests

This solution could be handful for some developers

Enjoy